# ResourceDictionary: Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#, wpf

I have application which refers to WPF class library `MainLibrary`. This class library gets resources from ResourceDictionary in another WPF class library `ResourceLibrary`.

In designer and at compile time **everything works fine**, resources from external ResourceDictionary load correctly, but at runtime app crashes with this exception:

> ''Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an
> exception.'
>
> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'ResourceLibrary, Culture=neutral' or one of its dependencies.
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I add ResourceDictionary in MainWindow of `MainLibrary` that way:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/ResourceLibrary;component/ResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Other observations:

1. If I add `ResourceDictionary.xaml` directly into the `MainLibrary`, app works with no exceptions. On the other hand, if I add another ResourceDictionary into the `ResourceLibrary`, the same exception is thrown.
2. I've tried to rebuild solution, restart VS and computer :)
3. Absolute path to `ResourceDictionary.xaml` solves the problem, but it's not acceptable.
4. Adding `ResourceLibrary` to main app references doesn't help.
5. `ResourceLibrary` is put properly into the `MainLibrary's` bin folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `pack://application:,,,/ResourceDictionary;` - shouldn't this be `pack://application:,,,/ResourceLibrary;`

Comment: yes, thank you, I mean ResourceLibrary. And I use ResourceLibrary

Comment: If `MainLibrary` is a WPF Class Library as you say, then why does it have a MainWindow at all? Did you create another MainWindow class in your `MainLibrary` that overrides the MainWindow in your application?

Comment: FYI, I was unable to reproduce your problem. Here I have created an app that references MainLibrary.dll that references ResourceLibrary.dll and utilizes a resource. [Download link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vIb-IWUksaxNmxkqXiue8rWNKgsyNXWs/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was very simple. In the latest versions of Visual Studio, when I add reference to `MainLibrary`, `ResourceLibrary` becomes referenced as nested reference.
But I tried to work in VS2015, where there is no such option. If I manually reference `ResourceLibrary` to **main app**, everything works fine.